# How to execute the mouseevent of qgraphicsitem only ? (ignoring the rest of mouseevent of qgraphicsview)

Tags: c++, qt

I know how to pass events from qgraphicsview to qgraphicsitem.
But the problem is after executing the mouseEvent of item ,i have to execute the mouse event of the view which is not desirable in my case.
so,the question is: "Is there a smart way to know if mousePress is on an item or on an empty space?"

Edit:The working code:

```
#include <QtGui>

class CustomView : public QGraphicsView
{

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
        qDebug() << "Custom view clicked.";

    }
};

class CustomItem : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
    {
        qDebug() << "Custom item clicked.";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    CustomItem item;
    item.setRect(20, 20, 60, 60);

    QGraphicsScene scene(0, 0, 100, 100);
    scene.addItem(&item);

    CustomView view;
    view.setScene(&scene);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Appling the same concept in a qgraphics scene instead of view

```
#include <QtGui>
class CustomScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
    {
        if(itemAt(event->scenePos()))
            QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent((event));
        else
        qDebug() << "Custom view clicked.";
    }
};
class CustomItem : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
    {
        qDebug() << "Custom item clicked.";
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    CustomItem item;
    item.setRect(20, 20, 60, 60);
    CustomScene scene;
    //scene().set
    scene.addItem(&item);
    QGraphicsView view;
    view.setScene(&scene);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine wether mouse event occured on item or not you can use [QGraphicsView::itemAt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#itemAt):

```
void CustomView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (itemAt(event->pos()))
        // Click on item
    else
        // Click on empty space
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey, a follow up question if I may... when I execute itemAt(event->pos()) I get QGraphicsItem(0). How can I "know" that this is viewport of QGraphicsView? Trying to determine when I clicked on empty space here.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 correct ways to solve your task:

`1.` Reimplement `QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent` and use `QGraphicsView::itemAt` to find clicked item.

`2.` Subclass `QGraphicsScene` and reimplement `QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent`. Its argument `event` contains position in scene coordinates, and you can use `QGraphicsScene::itemAt` to determine which item has been clicked.

`3.` Subclass `QGraphicsItem` (or any derived class) and reimplement `QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent`. It will be called only if this element was clicked.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,but when i tried it with qgraphicsScene it didn't work.I couldn't figure out the problem.